# Integer solutions of $3a^2 - 2a - 1 = n^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I've got an equation $3a^2 - 2a - 1 = n^2$, where $a,n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I put it in Wolfram Alpha and besides everything else it gives integer solution: see [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3a%5E2-2a-1=n%5E2,%20a%3E0,%20n%3E0&t=crmtb01).

For another equation (say, $3a^2 - 2a - 2 = n^2$, where $a,n \in \mathbb{N}$) Wolfram Alpha does not provide integer solutions: [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3a%5E2-2a-2=n%5E2,%20a%3E0,%20n%3E0).

Could you please tell me:

1. How does Wolfram Alpha determine existence of the integer solutions?
2. How does it find them?
3. What should I learn to be able to do the same with a pencil and a piece of paper (if possible)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should remember that generally the way to reduce a problem involving a quadratic polynomial with a first-degree term to a problem involving a quadratic polynomial with no first-degree term is _completing the square_.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe [Pell's Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) (and variants) would be useful.

The first one can be recast as

$$9a^2 - 6a - 3 = 3n^2$$ i.e.

$$(3a-1)^2 - 4 = 3n^2$$

You are looking for solutions to

$$ x^2 - 3y^2 = 4$$ such that $x = -1 \mod 3$.

There are standard techniques to solve Pell's equation and variants (see the wiki page linked above and mathworld page here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html) and I am guessing Wolfram Alpha is using one of them.

For the second I believe we get

$$x^2 - 3y^2 = 7$$

which does not have solutions, considering modulo $4$ (as pointed out by Adrián Barquero).

Comment: Beat me to it!  +1, this is perfect.

Comment: That the quadratic equation $x^2 - 3y^2 = 7$ has no solutions in integers can be seen by reducing modulo $4$ also.

Comment: @Adrian: Indeed... Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Lagrange showed how to reduce a general binary quadratic Diophatine equation to Pell form.

$$\rm a\ x^2 + b\ xy + c\ y^2 + d\ x + e\ y + f\ =\ 0 $$

reduces to a Pell equation as follows: put $\rm\ D = b^2-4ac,\ E = bd-2ae,\ F = d^2-4af\:.\ $ Then

$$\rm  D\ Y^2\ =\ (D\ y + E)^2 + D\ F - E^2,\quad\quad Y\ =\ 2ax + by + d $$

Therefore if we put $\rm\quad\ \ X\: =\: D\ y + E,\quad\ \ N\: =\: E^2 - D\ F\quad\ \ $ we obtain the Pell equation

$$\rm X^2 - D\ Y^2\ =\ N $$

Now you can apply standard techniques for solving Pell equations. They are a bit too complex to describe here. However, you can obtain complete step-by-step descriptions of the solution to any Pell equation using Dario Alpern's [Quadratic two integer variable equation solver.](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM)  For some  recent optimizations of Lagrange's algorithm see this paper H. C. Williams et al. [A new look at an old equation.](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-79456-1_2)

Answer (score 2):

The first one can also be easely reduced to pytagorean one:

$$3a^2 - 2a - 1= 4a^2-(a^2+2a+1) \,.$$

Thus

$$n^2+(a+1)^2=(2a)^2 \,.$$

Comment: This is an interesting observation, but it is not enough. The above Pythagorean equation is in fact a Pythagorean equation with a side condition, namely that $1$ more than half the hypotenuse is one of the legs.  True, we have a method for generating the integer solutions of $x^2+y^2=z^2$.  However, it may take substantial further work to satisfy the "side condition."